# Unable to create working installation media for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dvd, burning

I have tried to burn versions 12.4 LTS, and version 14.04 LTS to a DVD and the last time it said the disk was verified, but when I open the discs there is nothing burned on them. The image for 14.04 LTS is too big to burn on a 700Mb CD data disc, and I can't seem to get it into a DVD.

I have the 12.04.1 LTS disc that I had burned 2 years ago, it worked fine on several desktops, but it doesn't work on my laptop.  It installs but with errors and the programs won't start right. For some reason none of the ISO file downloads will work or burn on any of my laptops or desktops now. I have tried it on 5 altogether.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please clarify how you tried to burn the disk(s). You may wish to look at this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) on the official site.

Comment: This is a very unusual problem. What method are you using to burn the DVDs? I'd suggest trying a different program. Especially since it's not working on multiple PCs. If that does not work, you could try a non ubuntu .ISO and see if it's the .ISO that's the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As a general recommendations, check `md5sum` - you need to compare both: first, the `md5sum` of a downloaded file first. 
Second, the `md5sum` of a CD/DVD after you burn it. Both **must** match the original one, taken from [Ubuntu hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes):

If you run Linux currently and want to check this ISO without having CD/DVD ot USB, you can run it as LIVE from you hardrive. It will cover all the compliance, because my the time it has started, Kernel, modules, drivers, apps and most subsytems(audio, video, network) are running, which is the same for your machine after installation.

- Place your ISO file to `/live`:

`sudo mkdit /live`

`sudo cp somelinux.iso /live`

- Add new menu entry to the `grub.cfg`

`sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry 'ISO Ubuntu 14.04 2014 Live' --class os --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --group group_main {
                set isofile="/live/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso"

         insmod ext2
         insmod loopback
         insmod iso9660      
                loopback loop (hd0,msdos5)$isofile      

                linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=(loop)/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper persistent iso-scan/filename=/$isofile quiet splash --
                initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz


}
```

TO DO:

1. change in the menu entry above the code name for your partition, holding `/live/somelinux.iso`, in my case it's `hd0,msdos5` because it is on `/dev/sda5`/
2. change the file name from somelinux.iso to yours, in my case I have: `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso`

   - update GRUB

`sudo update-grub`

- reboot